# Magento is not updating Shipping cost on changing the Shipping method radio button

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I change the shipping method as you can see in the screenshot but magento does not refresh the inner page with the calculated total shipping cost.I think this is a bug in version 1.9. Here you can see the screenshot .Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

When I change the radio button from one shipping method the onestepcheckout does not refresh the inner page with calculated cost.
[image]

How can I refresh the inner page with javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code in available.phtml file

```
<?php if (!($_shippingRateGroups)): ?>
    <strong><?php echo Mage::helper('oscheckout')->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></strong>
<?php else: ?>
    <dl class="shipment-methods">

        <?php $methodcount = count($_shippingRateGroups); $check_default = 1;  foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
            <dd><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dd>
            <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                <dt style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                        <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?></li></ul></li></ul>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input <?php echo $check_default == 1 ? 'checked="checked"':'' ?> name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" />
                        <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"> <?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
                            <strong>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>

                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                (<?php echo Mage::helper('oscheckout')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </strong>
                        </label>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </dt>
            <?php  endforeach; $check_default++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endif;
 ?>
```

Add this script in the same file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php  if($methodcount >= 1): ?>
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
        shipping.loadReview();
        var payment_methods = $('ajax-payment-methods');
        //payment_methods.update('<div class="ajax-load">&nbsp;</div>');
        payment.reloadPaymentBlock();
//      reloadPaymethod();
    });
    <?php  endif; ?>
    $$('dl.shipment-methods input').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
        shipping.loadReview();
        var payment_methods = $('ajax-payment-methods');
        //payment_methods.update('<div class="ajax-load">&nbsp;</div>');
        payment.reloadPaymentBlock();
//      reloadPaymethod();
    });

</script>
```